# PostgresSQL Driver (version 12) rounding Java float Value to six digits

Tags: java, postgresql, floating-point, precision

I am using postgresql version 9.4.1.

I am in the process of upgrading the postgres driver from 9.1-901.jdbc4 (maven: postgresql:postgresql) to 42.2.5 (maven: org.postgresql: postgresql)

While doing so, I have observed a behavior which I am not able to understand.

I am trying to insert a value (float in Java) and in DB it is represented as Numeric.

1. When I try to store, "1234567" the value is stored as "1234570".
2. When i try to store, "123456" then the value is stored as "123456"

I am not able to understand the behavior of #1, where the digit 7 is dropped and 6 is getting rounded off to 7.

When I try #1 using older driver (9.1-901.jdbc4) then all is good.

Any thoughts on why this behavior and how i can fix it?

Java code snippet:

```
String inserSqlv2 = "INSERT INTO ABC (ID,IDNAME,NAME,FLOAT_VALUE, LASTMODIFIED) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";

Float val = Float.valueOf(1234567f);
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(inserSqlv2);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "d77e7ed20c2b650a148df390a8b3bce9");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "f199af000c2b650a397a8c537ba69d71");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "FLOT_CHECK");
preparedStatement.setFloat(4, val);
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(5, now);
preparedStatement.execute();
```

Maven dependency (for reference):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE rsa_rep.abc
(
    id character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    idname character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    name character varying(1020) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    float_value numeric
)
```

Logs on postgresql

```
=== when PostgreSQL driver 9.1-901.jdbc4 is used. ===========
2020-06-27 08:07:58.463 GMT [unknown] dba_user 5ef6fe5d.15c8 10/45 0 LOG:  execute <unnamed>: INSERT INTO ABC (ID,IDNAME,NAME,FLOAT_VALUE) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4)
2020-06-27 08:07:58.463 GMT [unknown] dba_user 5ef6fe5d.15c8 10/45 0 DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'd77e7ed20c2b650a148df390a8b3bce9', $2 = 'f199af000c2b650a397a8c537ba69d71', $3 = 'FLOT_CHECK', $4 = '1234567'

=== when PostgreSQL driver 42.2.5 is used ===========
2020-06-27 08:08:47.065 GMT PostgreSQL JDBC Driver dba_user 5ef6fe8d.eac 10/63 0 LOG:  execute <unnamed>: INSERT INTO ABC (ID,IDNAME,NAME,FLOAT_VALUE) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4)
2020-06-27 08:08:47.065 GMT PostgreSQL JDBC Driver dba_user 5ef6fe8d.eac 10/63 0 DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'd77e7ed20c2b650a148df390a8b3bce9', $2 = 'f199af000c2b650a397a8c537ba69d71', $3 = 'FLOT_CHECK', $4 = '1.234567e+06'
```

Comment: What is the definition of the Numeric column in the database?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, Default Numeric definition. Added the table definition for reference. Thanks.

Comment: Seems you'd better file a bugreport to Postgres. The problem is easily identified and reproduced. The origin is rather clear (reduction to 6 significant decimal digits is typical for `float` conversion) but could happen at server side.